# In Typescript, how to select a type from a union, using a literal type property of said type?

Tags: typescript

I have a reducer in react. The action can be one of 8 types, but for simplicity, let's imagine that there's only 2 types

```js
type Add = {
  type: 'add';
  id: string;
  value: string;
}

type Remove = {
  type: 'remove';
  id: string;
}

type Action = Add | Remove;
```

Instead of using a switch case, I'm using an object of handlers, where each handler is a function that handles a specific action

```js
const handlers = {
  add: (state, action) => state,
  remove: (state, action) => state,
  default: (state, action) => state,
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const handler = handlers[action.type] || handlers.default;
  return handler(state, action);
}
```

Now I want to type the `handlers` object appropriately. So the handler function should accept an action of type corresponding to its key in the `handlers` object.

```js
type Handlers = {
  [key in Action["type"]]: (state: State, action: Action) => State
//                                                ↑this here should be the action which has type
//                                                matching to it's key. So when the key is
//                                                'add', it should be of type Add, and so on.
}
```

All I could think of is to explicitly state the key and the matching action type. Is There a way to 'pick' the type from the union, according to the value of the key?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Extracting just the type is straightforward.

```js
type Add = {
    type: 'add';
    id: string;
    value: string;
}
  
type Remove = {
    type: 'remove';
    id: string;
}
  
type Action = Add | Remove;

type addType = Extract<Action, {type: 'add'}>;
```

You can create a mapped type to do this automatically for each element of the union.

```js
type OfUnion<T extends {type: string}> = {
    [P in T['type']]: Extract<T, {type: P}>
}
```

This is a mapped type. It's like a *type function*, it takes a type, transforms it, and returns that new type. So `OfUnion` is expecting something that is shaped like `T extends {type: string}`. This means it'll accept `{type: 'add'}` or a union type like `type Action = Add | Remove`. The important thing is every element of that union type has a `type: string` property.

When you have a union type and every option has a property in common, you can safely access that property (in this case, `type`). This gets *distributed*, so `Action['type']` gives us `'add' | 'remove'`. The mapped type is creating an object that has the keys `[P in T['type']]`, a.k.a. `'add' | 'remove'`!

The type of the `add` property should be the type of that action, `Add`. You can get to this with that `Extract<>` call I did. That essentially filters a union to only include elements that match a certain type. In this case, filter to just something that matches `{type: 'add'}`. The only option that matches this is the `{type: 'add', id: string, value: string}` object, so that's what it's set to.

Now you have an object that looks like this:

```js
{
    add: {
        type: 'add';
        id: string;
        value: string;
    },
    remove: {
        type: 'remove';
        id: string;
    }
}
```

That's great! But we need to convert that to a handler. So the handler is still going to have `add` and `remove` keys, but instead of the object types, they will be functions that *take* the object type and return whatever.

```js
type Handler<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: (variant: T[P]) => any
}
```

Here an example of `P` would be `'add'` and `T[P]` would be that `Add` type. So now the handler should take in an `Add` object, and do something with it. That's exactly what we want.

now you can write a match function that is type-safe w/ autocomplete:

```js
function match<
    T extends {type: string},
    H extends Handler<OfUnion<T>>,
> (
    obj: T,
    handler: H,
): ReturnType<H[keyof H]> {
    return handler[obj.type as keyof H]?.(obj as any);
}
```

Note that you need to use *extends* here to infer the specific type of H. You'll need that fully specified type to get the return types of each branch.

[edited playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvAUFKpIC4oDkAhggQNyZQCWc+AzsAE5UB2A5hVgG5EA2ArhHpNWHdAF906HNABKEALYB7LtBQYsM-AUaKVEcpRrDm7CpOnhoAZWBFgatJJmwAxsCpKWyWAigAfKHllVQpLSCgAeQAzAFUWTxYAHgAVKAgADwcWODo0LSgGUzZxAD4fDSwoAG0ABWpvFOqCGQIAXTb8AFEsxiJ3VIAafKt8WrKJcOgACSIc3ghGVPL1Siw6hqgAawgQJWioFM6oAAoeZjngfCbatoBKZHK5kEn0aP4Wd0SoBXtXAAskmtDukshAcnlUAUiqJxINgdNQdlclBZvNFkkYvFEstSvDyidgUoAEYAK2u8KqUH+czgC0Y+Gm8Lu+HkwH4jBYKSsSWm1R2ewO0za5UqWF07M51Np9OqJNJADoXEQ8gL9qi2gB+BUneVQFX6lggO7mKSuLwMKC6OD8VyLHwnBj2IRQWzO4b9DxefAwL5eB5Icq-YAAk6exLDSokWj6v3eQOFOwOSlWvSqfDhryPRPuiR3dBAA)

The `match()` function needs to take an object, which will have a union type like `Action` and then restrict the handler object it's expect to a certain contract (the handler types we created just now). It's better to do this as a function rather than for each case because then you don't need to keep rewriting the type definitions! The function will bring them. It's also better to do this agnostically, without the state object, because you can still use the state object inside of the handler branches. Lookup 'closures' for more info but you can also take it on faith from me that the `state` object will be in scope. But now, we can also use `match` in places where `state` isn't relevant, like *in the .jsx*.

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => match(action, {
  add: ({id, value}) => state,
  remove: ({id}) => state,
})
```

Believe me, *using* these types is easier than writing them. You need advanced typescript knowledge to write them, but any beginner can use them.

---

You may be interested in [my library `variant`, which does this exact thing](https://paarthenon.github.io/variant/docs/intro). In fact these examples are just [simplified versions of my library code](https://github.com/paarthenon/variant/blob/master/src/variant.ts#L198). My `match` function will automatically restrict the handler object you are passing in and the return type will be the union of all the handler branches.

You are welcome to steal this, or, try out the library for yourself. It will include much more for you in this same direction.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) conditional type to extract a type from a union based on a base type of the desired type.

```
type Handlers = {
  [key in Action["type"]]: (state: State, action: Extract<Action, { type: key }>) => State
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvAUFKpIC4oDkAhggQNyZQCWc+AzsAE5UB2A5hVgG5EA2ArhHpNWHdAF906HNABKEALYB7LtBQYsM-AUaKVEcpRrDm7CpOnhoAZWBFgatJJmwAxsCpKWyWAigAfKHllVQpLSCgACSIWOF4IRjofDSgAbQBrCBBqbxh3TxZUgCIZIoBdMvwACgZ7IShbOoAaKCJ8r3wAUQAPJjbgAB48jy8W1GwrfEzs8QA+AEpkWYa7BwkgA)

Comment: It throws an error when I use the handler in the reducer.
It says 'The intersection was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types.'
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvAUFKpIC4oDkAhggQNyZQCWc+AzsAE5UB2A5hVgG5EA2ArhHpNWHdAF906HNABKEALYB7LtBQYsM-AUaKVEcpRrDm7CpOnhoAZWBFgatJJmwAxsCpKWyWAigAfKHllVQpLSCgACSIWOF4IRjofDSgAbQBrCBBqbxh3TxZUgCIZIoBdMvwACgZ7IShbOoAaKCJ8r3wAUQAPJjbgAB48jy8W1GwrfEzs8QA+AEpkWYa7BwkpVy8GKAALGLiEunxo2PjE5MoSWiga1YgW-oLFpGXahybKXRD62+bW9pYz1edw+Fk2LG2ujg-FcCR8vwc+Ea73+IxY+GGTyWu32ZzoqUeXgAdDIygj7qinkA)

Comment: @AhmadMayo you will not get that to type check (even with a manually written `Handlers`  type). Ts can't corelate the type of `action` and `handlers[action.type]`, your only choice is a type assertion or that `handlers[action.type](state, action as never)`

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach you can take. I added some code comments to explain my approach:

```
type Add = {
  type: 'add';
  id: string;
  value: string;
}

type Remove = {
  type: 'remove';
  id: string;
}

type Action = Add | Remove;
type State = any // replace with a type to define the shape of your state

// All reducing functions have the same interface
type ReducingFunction = (state: State, action: Action) => State

// Create a type with the Action type as the key, and a reducing callback as the value
// Finally, add `default` to this type
type Handlers = Record<Action['type'], ReducingFunction> & { default: ReducingFunction }

const handlers: Handlers = {
  add: (state, action) => state,
  remove: (state, action) => state,
  default: (state, action) => state,
}

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  const handler = handlers[action.type] || handlers.default;
  return handler(state, action);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvAUFKpIC4oDkAhggQNyZQCWc%20AzsAE5UB2A5hVgG5EA2ArhHpNWHdAF906HNABKEALYB7LtBQYsM-AUaKVEcpRrDm7CpOnhoMAMbAqSlslgIoAHyjzlqijKgBlYCJgNSgiFhAoAHooqF0wXiIbaAB3KmAACzDsK2wlKDgIADNWaEzoOgyiSCglIqgQJX5GKAZgiCkY2F5eOIg4fhtRKCL%20FjsHFjooKtVsDIqiBWhWEMYipI6-eQGh9gAxMYnHZwAKNpD8QPaAGjDjlnxbe0cASmQAPgCgkM7YgGFdO1sn40pl5tYHjkakRpuUoABrCAgO7hRBEPq7YY2Pi8ABGSQRYThCygPAEHS6%201YuJRYVcAANCht%20LxgAy8vMqHCrJYagAJNG8CCMaYoeQ2JSMOAAHmekwA2gQZAQALp3HaDUSHcYvFhfABkaAKxSIrOA%20E1ezYOqhFklU2AMyFIro%20EFLDgwtFzg09NoUHOPwgqIe7yQXwuIcoum8QkDUdDevDkeDN0ozLNbPwQdu92Tn1aaYkUgdDExgxFZyjVzT%20cmTzDhb9ZadVU93uc7a9roVST1ADoZKr3B5u966APM%20bOH1gM0nOORbmQknJq9zEA)

Comment: but now the handlers are not appropriately typed. The add handler should only accept an action of type Add, but not Remove, and vice-versa. If I for some reason tried to access the `content` property of the action, inside the remove handler, the compiler will not complain, but it should